# how to add Unallocatated disk to lvm2 root in fedora?

Tags: fedora, root, disk

my lvm2 root in fedora already full, and i have 20.30GB unallocated disk, but i cant use Gparted to use it, so is there any method to move that unallocated disk??

Comment: please post output of `lsblk -f` so we can see what we're working with.

Comment: Are you trying to partition the disk so that you can add it to your LV? If so, you can just use fdisk. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You use `fdisk` to create a new partition (20.30GB unallocated disk), then follow this step to extend your existing LV:

1. Initialize the new partition for use by LVM using `pvcreate
   /dev/
2. Get the current VG using `vgdisplay`
3. Extend the existing VG, `vgextend
4. Increase the LV, `lvextend -L+20G /dev/<VG name>/<LV name>`

Comment: I broke my filesystem , I think I made something wrong, how I can I rebuild initramfs in rescue mode? When I boot, my fedora in emergency mode , and the logs say , failed to start default.target

Comment: @Harmnot try this `dracut --force --regenerate-all`

Comment: I already re install my fedora, thx that your kind solutions ;)